# How to set the background color of a plot in pyxplot?

Tags: pyxplot

What is the best way to set the background color of a PNG plot in pyxplot?

I suspect that it could probably be done using a box command in multi plot mode, but I'm wondering if there are any more elegant ways?

UPDATE

I tried using boxes in multi-plot mode.  It partially works in that I am able to set the background color of the inside of the plot area.  However, the boxes do not extend out into the xlabel/ylabel area, so it is not a true workaround for backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I did which *did* work (although extremely hack-ish) was to make the plot a transparent PNG.  You could then place the plot on an HTML page and control the background color externally, or if you want to bake a colored background into the plot you could do something like this with Imagemagick:

> convert transparent_plot.png -background black -flatten plot_with_black_background.png

Haven't found any easier ways yet.  Perhaps something I missed.

Only other thought I had was to play with the LaTeX preamble to see if that would somehow let me control things.